# Transfer devices from one Apple dev account to another

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I have about 60 devices registered under one developer account in the Apple dev portal. I need  to add those same devices for a new app under a completely different dev account. I'm really, really hoping I don't have to enter each device manually. Is there a way to export/import or transfer these devices?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dev portal lets you import a text file with a list of devices. But the dev portal doesn't provide any way to export a current list of devices. So you will need to copy and paste the device details into the text file before you can import the devices into the dev portal.

To do the import, view the device list in the dev portal. Then tap the + icon to add new devices. You can either enter a single device or choose to upload the file. The upload section lets you download a sample file so you can see the format.

BTW - this won't be a "transfer". The devices you add to the new account will remain on the old account too.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the import. You would think it wouldn't be much work for Apple to provide an export button.

Answer (score 1):

You can register them on the other account (and as many other accounts as you'd like), but you won't be able to remove them from the current one until your contract expires. You can disable them, but you can't delete them.

Answer (score 1):

You have to re-enter each device ID manually, there is no export option for the list in the Apple dev portal.

Answer (score 1):

There is no export, but there is an import.  In the past I have used cut and paste to grab the list from the first account, then edited that in a text file so that it had the appropriate format for import.  Here is the format from one of their sample files

```
Device ID   Device Name
A123456789012345678901234567890123456789    NAME1
B123456789012345678901234567890123456789    NAME2
```

Comment: Fat fingers and bad proof-reading. :-(

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in previous answers, there isn't a way to transfer devices from one account to another; you can only register the same set of devices in the other account.  Instead of manually copy-pasting from the Certificates, Identities, and profile tool and thus being subject to potential copy-paste error or fat-fingering, I've used Matt Thompson's 'Cupertino' command-line utility: https://github.com/nomad/cupertino

The first three commands in the readme will export your device list to a terminal window from which you can straighten up for formatting for the format Apple expects and batch upload your devices to the second account.

This keeps the copy-pasting to a minimum, and only requires minimal edits of the Cupertino output.  I used a variation on this process for syncing devices between my dev accounts.